Is $f(x)=x^a$ with $a=-\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$ the only solution to the equation $f(x)f(f(x))=x$?
I came up with this question on my own and was curious if there were any other possible solutions. I used $f^n(x)=x^{a^n}$ where $f^n(x)$ represents the $n$th iteration of $f(x)$ and solved $x^{a^n+a}=x$ and got $a=-\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$. I was curious if there are any other solutions. I know there can't be any more of the form $f(x)=x^a$ but I don't know how to prove there exists or does not exist other solutions.
Also, if there does exist other functions such that $f(x)f(f(x))=x$, are there a finite or infinite amount of functions that satisfy this condition?

Compare with the answer here.

You can define another function equal to either of the functions you provided when $x\neq0$, but is $0$ when $x=0$. This satisfies your functional equation.

The number of these functions is infinite and it is easy to construct a lot of them. A first natural approach is to define from the solutions $f(x)=x^{a_1}$ and $g(x)=x^{a_2}$, with $a_{1,2}=-\frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$, a new solution:
$$h(x)=\begin{cases} f(x) \ \ \text{ if  } x\leq 0 \\ g(x) \ \ \text{ if  } x\geq 0 \end{cases} $$
You can modify the domain of $h$ as you want so that your equation is satisfied by an infinite   number of functions.
